# good 3d Video carousel script

Tags: php, joomla1.5

Can anyone get me a good script for video carousel. I want it to use it with my Joomla/php.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to look like? Do you have an example? There are several developers that build nice carousel type components. You should check out

1. Gavick - http://tools.gavick.com/
2. Rocket Theme - http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla
3. Yootheme - http://www.yootheme.com/tools/

I've used extensions from all 3 and they work pretty well.